# Make scene available in other tabs - React Native Router Flux

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I got my tabbar setup as follows:

```
<Router>
            <Stack key="root">
                <Scene
                    key="tabbar"
                    tabs
                    tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar}
                >
                    <Scene 
                        key="home" 
                        title="HOME"
                    >
                        <Scene 
                            key="home"
                            component={Home}
                        />
                        <Scene 
                            key="audioPlayer"
                            component={AudioPlayer}
                            title="AUDIO PLAYER"
                        />
                        <Scene 
                            key="notification"
                            component={Notification}
                            title="NOTIFICATIONS"
                        />

                        <Scene 
                            key="search"
                            component={Search}
                            title="SEARCH"
                        />

                    </Scene>                

                    <Scene 
                            key="latest"
                            title="LATEST"
                            component={Latest}
                    />

                    <Scene 
                            key="offline"
                            component={Offline}
                            title="OFFLINE"
                    />

                    <Scene
                        key="more"
                        component={More}
                        title="MORE"
                    />

                </Scene> 
            </Stack>
        </Router>
```

**CASE :**

I got 4 tabs named as : Home, Latest, Offline & More.

I can navigate to audioPlayer scene easily from Home tab.

```
 Actions.audioPlayer();
```

Because I have added audioPlayer scene inside that Home tab scene.

**PROBLEM :**

***How to navigate to that audioPlayer scene inside of Home scene from the latest scene?***

Any Suggestions.
Should I have to add audioPlayer scene inside Latest scene for navigation?

Thanks.

P.S: I don't want to put that audioPlayer scene inside my latest tab.
I don't know if that's the only solution.

**UPDATE:**

If I do ,

```
Actions.audioPlayer();
```

from latest tab , I am navigated to home tab and from there to audioPlayer scene.

I want to have that navigation inside of Latest tab . :)

**UPDATE 2:**

If I put audioPlayer scene outside of tabbar . I can navigate to audioPlayer scene like I want.
But I got one problem.
How can I get that bottom tabbar in that audioPlayer scene?

Comment: you can do this with redux navigation.

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar can you please write an answer or you have a link to example?

Comment: I am using react-native-router-flux currently

Comment: Did you try this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206782/react-native-router-flux-navigate-from-main-scene-to-child

Comment: @WaheedAkhtar on trying that I am moved to Home tab.
What I want is , I want to be on the same tab and move to audioPlayer scene .

Just like our native iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your second update (putting the audioPlayer scene outside of the tabs), try that approach while adding the prop `clone` to the AudioPlayer scene.

```
<Scene 
  key="audioPlayer"
  component={AudioPlayer}
  title="AUDIO PLAYER"
  clone
 />
```

#### Edit: To explain what clone does

From the docs

> Scenes marked with clone will be treated as templates and cloned into the current scene's parent when pushed.

That means the pushed scene `audioPlayer` will be rendered using the parent tab scene as template thus rendering the tab buttons.