# Go to sub-scene tabs - react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux

This is my hierarchical structure of router:

```
<Tabs
  key='tabbar'
  backToInitial
  onTabOnPress={() => {
    console.log('Back to initial and also print this');
  }}
  swipeEnabled
  hideNavBar={true}
>
  <Scene
    title='Profilo'
    key='profile'
    component={Profile}
    tabBarLabel='Profilo'
    icon={TabBarIcon}
    name='ios-person'
    titleStyle={{
      fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular', 
      fontSize: 24, 
      color: '#00b0ff'
    }}
  >
    <Scene
      title='adsf'
      key='vehicle'
      component={Vehicle}
      titleStyle={{
        fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular', 
        fontSize: 24, 
        color: '#00b0ff'
      }}
    />
  </Scene>

</Tabs>
```

If I am on the `Profilo` page and I wont to go to the `Vehicle` page, I use `Actions.vehicle()` but I obtain this error:

> Actions.vehicle() is not a function

I already try with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41063797/6608222), but this also doesn't work
How can I resolve this problem?

The Result of a propesed `snack` is the following: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an action scene key will require your scene to be on the same level as your other scenes, i.e. the `vehicle` scene cannot be a child component of `profile`.

In addition, you will need a `Stack` component to house both `profile` and `vehicle` scenes so that you can call `Actions.{key}` to access the scenes properly.

I have included a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/rnrf-example-1) here for you to play with it. :)

Proposed solution:

```
<Tabs
  key='tabbar'
  backToInitial
  onTabOnPress={() => {
    console.log('Back to initial and also print this');
  }}
  swipeEnabled
  hideNavBar={true}
>
  <Stack
    title='ProfiloStack'
    key='profileStack'
  >
  <Scene
    title='Profilo'
    key='profile'
    component={Profile}
    tabBarLabel='Profilo'
    icon={TabBarIcon}
    name='ios-person'
    titleStyle={{
      fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular', 
      fontSize: 24, 
      color: '#00b0ff'
    }}
  />
    <Scene
      title='adsf'
      key='vehicle'
      component={Vehicle}
      titleStyle={{
        fontFamily: 'RobotoRegular', 
        fontSize: 24, 
        color: '#00b0ff'
      }}
    />
  </Stack>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: that's strange. it is working on my expo snack. how does your updated code with the `Stack` component look? i can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: When I open and start your expo snack, the error was generated

Comment: Erm. It is not going to work on `browser`. You need to select `Android` or `iOS`.

Comment: I run your snack on my `Android`... In my question, I add the result of run your `snack`

Comment: Okay. I can see a couple of problems there. You will need to restructure your scenes by enclosing both scenes within a `Stack` and named it differently. I've updated my answer to include a proposed solution.